# Singleton method for Redis connection in Python

Tags: python, singleton, redis

Here's my class for providing a singleton instance of a Redis connection. What do you think?

```
from redis import StrictRedis
import os

class RedisConnection(object):
    REDIS_URL = os.environ['REDIS_URL']

    def __init__(self):
        self._redis = StrictRedis.from_url(self.REDIS_URL)

    def redis(self):   
        return self._redis

    the_instance = None
    @classmethod
    def singleton(cls):
        if cls.the_instance == None:
            print "assigning!"
            cls.the_instance = cls().redis()
        return cls.the_instance
```

Answer (score 6):

The [Singleton pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) is a way to work around the absence of global variables in Java. But Python has global variables, and it's usually possible to write shorter and simpler initialization code if you use them, for example:

```
import os

from redis import StrictRedis

_connection = None

def connection():
    """Return the Redis connection to the URL given by the environment
    variable REDIS_URL, creating it if necessary.

    """
    global _connection
    if _connection is None:
        _connection = StrictRedis.from_url(os.environ['REDIS_URL'])
    return _connection
```

Alternatively, you could *memoize* the function, for example using [`functools.lru_cache`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.lru_cache):

```
from functools import lru_cache
import os

from redis import StrictRedis

@lru_cache(maxsize=1)
def connection():
    """Return the Redis connection to the URL given by the environment
    variable REDIS_URL, creating it if necessary.

    """
    return StrictRedis.from_url(os.environ['REDIS_URL'])
```